# cannot parse response alamofire swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to make a Get request with Alamofire for swift. When I run in Simulator or device with iOS 10 it works fine. When I run my app on Devices with iOS 9.x or prior, I'm getting "cannot parse response". The JSON response is right. I checked in postman.

There's my code:

```
lass func getStores(latitude:Float, longitude: Float,  completion : @escaping (Array<Store>?, NSError?) -> ()) {
let latString: String = "\(latitude)"
let lonString: String = "\(longitude)"
var listStores: Array<Store> = []
let urlFull : String = ConstantHelper.kUrlStore


Alamofire.request(urlFull, method: .get, parameters: ["latitude":latString, "longitude": lonString], encoding: JSONEncoding(options: []),  headers: [:]).validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                if let repoJSON = response.result.value {
                    print(repoJSON)
                    let jsonArray = repoJSON as! NSArray
                    for item in jsonArray {
                        guard let store = Store(json: item as! JSON) else
                        {
                            print("Issue deserializing model")
                            return
                        }
                        listStores.append(store)
                    }
                    completion(listStores, nil)
                }
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                    completion(nil, error as NSError?)
                break
            }
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: According to my experience, it's possible that you see the JSON correct in Postman but then JSONSerialization will say it's corrupt. Please show your JSON response instead. Maybe the link if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with the following code without JSON enconding in request:

```
Alamofire.request(urlFull, method: .get, parameters: ["latitude":latString, "longitude": lonString]).validate()
```

I don't know why works in Swift 2.x and in Swift 3.0 with iOS 10 with encoding and don't in ios 9...but the code above works in all situations. And its really no needed to enconding this request